# Pass property getter to linq expression function

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to take a method and make it generic, and I'm a little stuck because the method uses Linq to look at elements.  Here's the example method:

```cs
private List<int> GetListFromIDS(string ids, IEnumerable<SubSpace_Function> data)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ids))
        return null;

    var list = ids
        .Split(new char[] { ',' })
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
        .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim()));

    return data
        .Where(x => list.Contains(x.Function_Id)))
        .Select(x => x.Function_Id)
        .ToList();
}
```

The parts that change are the type (`SubSpace_Function`) and the property to lookup `Function_ID`.

I know I can just change the `SubSpace_Function` part to `T` in the generic method signature, but since each type will have it's own property to lookup, I'm not sure how to 'pass' in something like `Function_Id`.

Comment: `Func<T, int>`  would be the natural way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do with `Func`:

```
private List<int> GetListFromIDS<T>(string ids, IEnumerable<T> data, Func<T, IEnumerable<int>, bool> filterExpression, Func<T, int> selectExpression)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ids))
        return null;

    var list = ids
        .Split(',') // simplify
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
        .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim()));

    return data
        .Where(x => filterExpression(x, list))
        .Select(selectExpression)
        .ToList();
}
```

And call using:

```
var data = GetListFromIDS<SubSpace_Function>(
    "123,123,123", 
    someList,
    (x, list) => list.Contains(x.Function_Id), 
    x => x.Function_Id);
```

---

Another way is to call the select `Func` inline:

```
private List<int> GetListFromIDS<T>(string ids, IEnumerable<T> data, Func<T, int> selectExpression)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ids))
        return null;

    var list = ids
        .Split(',') // simplify
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
        .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim()));

    return data
        .Where(x => list.Contains(selectExpression(x)))
        .Select(selectExpression)
        .ToList();
}
```

And call using:

```
var data = GetListFromIDS<SubSpace_Function>(
    "123,123,123", 
    someList,
    x => x.Function_Id);
```

Comment: Is there a way to encapsulate the `list` part into the method itself so that each caller doesn't have to pass the list.Contains part?

Comment: @Gargoyle There you go

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much for the great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this focused on generics, but I took the approach of using an interface instead:

```
interface ISubSpaceFunction
{
    int FunctionId { get; }
}

class Foo : ISubSpaceFunction
{
    public int FunctionId => FooMethodForFunctionId();

    private int FooMethodForFunctionId()
    {
        //do foo function id stuff
        throw new NotImplementedException();//so it compiles
    }
}

class Bar : ISubSpaceFunction
{
    public int FunctionId => BarMethodForFunctionId();

    private int BarMethodForFunctionId()
    {
        //do bar function id stuff
        throw new NotImplementedException();//so it compiles
    }
}

static class MyClass
{
    private static List<int> GetListFromIds(string idsString, IEnumerable<ISubSpaceFunction> subSpaceFunctions)
    {
        var ids = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(idsString) ?
            Enumerable.Empty<int>() :
            idsString.Split(new[] { ',' })
                     .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                     .Select(x => x.Trim())
                     .Select(int.Parse);

        var idSet = new HashSet<int>(ids);

        return subSpaceFunctions.Select(ssf => ssf.FunctionId)
                                .Where(ids.Contains)
                                .ToList();
    }
}

class Example
{
    public void Test()
    {
        string ids = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";

        var subSpaceFunctions = new ISubSpaceFunction[] { new Foo(), new Bar() };

        var results = MyClass.GetListFromIds(ids, subSpaceFunctions);
    }
}
```

My attitude on this and related matters is that the code to get the Property value for each particular type has to go *somewhere*, so it might as well go in the Type's class.  This ensures that if the Property's value is needed elsewhere, there is no duplication.  This also allows for mixing multiple types that satisfy ISubSpaceFunction, as is done in the example, and you could easily have the interface also specify some common method to be used elsewhere.

I also prefer returning empty collections over null when writing these kinds of LINQ based transformation methods in order to minimize null checking "down the pipeline," but a "fail fast" use case may call for a null return value.